# How to Update order in sql of Jquery table after dragging and dropping

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, ado.net, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a jquery table , which I have made sortable( can drag and drop items) using below code.

```
$("#tblLookup1 tbody").sortable({
            items: 'tr',
            cursor: 'pointer',
            axis: 'y',
            dropOnEmpty: false,
            start: function (e, ui) {
                ui.item.addClass("selected");
            },
```

Now once I have manually dragged the rows according to my need, I want an update button which saves the new order so that when I visit the page next time I see the new order and not original order.

My Approach: I have a column by the name Priority , which has the initial order, I am trying to update that priority after drag and drop is completed and send the list of new priorities and update the database...
How can I achieve this?
Project is c# ,mvc ado.net based

Comment: Given that you appear to have made no attempt, I'm not sure what answer you're expecting here. SO is for getting help debugging code that you've written, not to have others write code for you.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan What I tried is , in my table I have added a priority column which contains the sequence of the rows, I am trying to update those priority after drag and drop is completed and then pass it to controller, but not sure of how to achieve that, so was trying to see if anyone has a alternative approach

Comment: That seems a reasonable approach.  What part are you having difficulty with?   Reading the new order?  Associated row-Ids with the new order?  Making an ajax $.post?  Updating the DB?

Comment: @freedomn-m giving updated row Ids to new order. like lets say I have 3 columns , Id ,Name and Priority. Now after drag and drop gets completed the first element should get priority 1, second priority 2 and so on...

Answer (score 0):

> I have 3 columns: Id, Name and Priority

You can loop through `$("table tbody tr").each((idx, tr) =>` to get the new index of each tr and copy this into the priority value (cell text, hidden input, etc).

Assuming position destination is 3rd column:

```
    $("table tbody tr").each((idx, tr) => {
        $("td:nth-child(3)", tr).text(idx);
    });
```

Add to the sorting's `stop:` function to happen immediately, gives:

```js
$("#tbl tbody").sortable({
  items: 'tr',
  cursor: 'pointer',
  axis: 'y',
  dropOnEmpty: false,
  start: function(e, ui) {
    ui.item.addClass("selected");
  },
  
  stop: function(e, ui) {
    $("#tbl tbody tr").each((idx, tr) => {
        $("td:nth-child(3)", tr).text(idx);
    });
  }

});
```

```html
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<table id='tbl'>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>ID</td>
      <td>label</td>
      <td>pos</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>first</td>
      <td>0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>second</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>third</td>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

---

To $.post these, it might be easier to have hidden inputs in the row, eg, with example Razor:

```
<tr>
  <td>
    @item.Name
    <input type='hidden' name="id[]" value='@item.Id'>
    <input type='hidden' name="priority[]" class='priority'>
  </td>
</tr>
```

(just make sure they are in a `<td>` other the browser will move them out of the `<table>`)

then you can update this in the above loop by replacing `...text(idx)` with:

```
$(tr).find(".priority").val(idx);
```

Comment: Thanks @freedomn-m , I am clear with the first part for posting part can you tell any article I can refer to? Not fully sure what to do buddy

Comment: Also , why did you use hidden inputs here

```
<tr>
  <td>
    @item.Name
    <input type='hidden' name="id[]" value='@item.Id'>
    <input type='hidden' name="priority[]" class='priority'>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: The hidden inputs allow you to either just submit() a `<form>` or serialize() a form for your own $.post - assuming the `<form>` is outside the table.   Easier than building your own `data` from text values and hidden from the user as they don't need to see that.